# Finding End Of Record (EOR) in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

How to find End Of Record(EOR) in a table at Crystal report environment?

Comment: Do you want to know when you are at the end of the recordset, or you want to find values in the last record?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: i want to know when the recordset end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `OnLastRecord`, which will return a boolean value.

If you are on the last record of a recordset, `OnLastRecord` will return TRUE.